# event.preventDefault() from @HostListener for form element

Tags: angular, typescript, dom-events

I have a component that listens to a `submit` event of a form in the host component. And the form has a (ngSubmit) bound. I want to stop form submission. But the following doesn't work:
It hits `submit listened` and then, also calls `submitForm()` method.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
export class ComponentClass {

  @HostListener('submit',['$event'])
  public onSubmit(event : Event){
    console.log('submit listened');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

  }
}
```

In host component:

```
<my-component>
  <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">...
  </form>
</my-component>
```

Comment: can you try adding `return false` inside `onSubmit`

Comment: That is also not working. I think both are independently receiving the event.

Comment: see this: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3536-host-bindings-dont-prevent-default-event-behavior-until-after-all-event-handlers-have-executed-in-angular-7-1-1.htm

Comment: I solved it like `<my-component (submit)="submitForm()">`, but that is not what I wanted. Because, it alters the normal way of operation, if I want to ship it as a library.

Comment: Just to add on my previous comment, I don't know why, but (submit) event was causing wired behavior. so changed event name to `(formSubmit)`